# Track the calls of a command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, process-monitoring

To quickly explain the goal of my question, I use Ubuntu mate with an apple keyboard.
To make the keyboard working properly, I had to remap some keys using `xmodmap`, such as interchanging the `#`/`@` with `<`/`>` .

The custom map is done in a `~/.Xmodmap` as it should be.
To load it automatically, I added `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` to my `.zshrc`.

But, after a while, the xmodmap configuration is fully erased.
To reconfigure it, I have to open a new terminal or manually call the `xmodmap` command.

This problem is already known on gnome and I cannot find a working solution to keep my xmodmap always working.

To solve the problem, I think I have to find which package/command causes the squashing of my custom configuration by avoiding doubts one by one.

I know some commands which potentially can reset the `xmodmap` configuration such as `setxkbmap` .

To be sure my problem is coming from it, I want make my session listening on this command (`setxkbmap`), sort as I know when it's called.

My question is the following:

How can I monitor calls of a command (maybe by writing in a log file, I just need to know if it was called during the session) ?

Also, if you know another alternative to debug or keep my configuration intact during the session, it's even better.

Thank's by advance for every answers I would get.

Comment: If this question doesn't should be on this stack exchange, please say me, I'm a bit lost between server oriented stack exchanges.

Comment: See http://www.shibuvarkala.com/2009/04/howto-enable-process-accounting-in.html for how to enable process accounting in Linux. If you have further questions, askubuntu.com might be a better place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a [shell wrapper](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/wrapper.html) could help you.

Rename setxkbmap to setxkbmap.bin

Then create a script named setxkbmap to sit in the same place where the original was, with the content:

```
echo "[$(date)] [ppid $PPID] $@" >> /var/tmp/setxkbmap.log
exec setxkbmap.bin $@
```

You can log the the user id or whatever you think could be helpful